# Load WebPage in Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to load a particular web page into my windows phone app. How do I do it?
The page should be loaded within my app and not in any other browser that is installed in the phone i.e  the requested page should not launch the browser

Comment: Try WebBrowser control : http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/WebBrowser_Control_Techniques_in_Windows_Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431797%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

example: http://mrbool.com/how-to-utilize-web-browser-control-in-windows-phone-7/25798

and check this too: (Windows Phone WebBrowser control tips) http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/09/17/windows-phone-webbrowser-control-tips.aspx